# Internet Explorer serves up unknown file type

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I have a web server on port 80 and port 81. IE can connect to the server on either port. This worked fine until I installed an application with a file type (.TPJ) that had a MIME type of text/xml on the client PC. At that point IE no longer opened the web site, but offered to download a file *serverName.TPJ*. The file contained the correct information from the web site.

I changed the installer for the application so it didn't register the MIME type. Now IE on the client PC offers to download a file with unknown file type. Note that the application has never been installed on the server PC.

The problem occurs with IE7. It doesn't occur with Firefox, Safari, or Chrome.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. There is a left-over entry in the registry for the text/xml MIME type. It can be restored to the default value by re-registering the MSXML3.DLL.

```
regsvr32 msxml3.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\text/xml]
"CLSID"="{48123BC4-99D9-11D1-A6B3-00C04FD91555}"
"Extension"=".xml"
"Encoding"=hex:08,00,00,00